# How to implement a logical shift (to the left) by 8 bits?

Tags: binary, lc3

I am trying to determine how to shift the last 8 bits (i.e. byte) of a 16 bit (two byte) word to the left using the LC-3 instruction set.

For example,

```
0000 0000 1111 1111 -> 1111 1111 0000 0000
```

Comment: What language are you using? Is this in assembly? Are you using C? Go? Ruby? 

Without know more, it is impossible to say how to do it.

Comment: @martinclayton - Yes, figured that out. Should have been in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now understanding that you are talking about LC-3, I found the [LC-3b Miroarchitecture](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~patt/07s.360N/handouts/360n.appC.pdf) and this presentation on the [Instruction Set](http://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmpe012/Summer08/notes/06_LC3_ISA_markup.pdf) referenced.

You need to implement a [logical shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift). Specifically a [logical shift left](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/assemblytutorial/Chapter-12/ass12_2.html). A number of ways are available to do this.

If you understand [binary arithmetic](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/BinaryMath/BinaryMath.html), you will be able to do this in a straightforward way.

Comment: RyPope - You are correct that it doesn't have instructions for performing logical shifts. That is why he will have to implement it himself. But it does have all of the base instructions required to implement logical shift left and right.

Answer (score 2):

To do a left shift all you have to do is add the value to itself. Create a simple loop to do this 8 times.

Something like

```
LD R1, count
loop
    LD R0, word
    ADD R0, R0, R0 ;Left Shift
    ADD R1, R1, -1 ;Decrement shift counter
    BRp loop       ;We still have shifts, go back to loop

HALT
count .fill #8
```